# If I replace the cassette on my road bike, should I replace the whole drivetrain?

Tags: chain, cassette, chainring, drivetrain

Relatively new to road cycling, have bought a 2nd hand bike and am thinking some parts of the drivetrain need replacing. Have tried to find this online and can't find any answers. Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, a cassette will last two or three chains, and a set of chainrings will last two or three cassettes.  But, of course, if chain replacement is neglected then both cassette and chainrings wear faster.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Ashley. We generally advise new members to take the [tour] to make best use of the site. Of course, yours is a common question; while the linked question doesn't look the same, we think the answers will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the new cassette has the same gears (# teeth) as the old one, you may not need to. If your chain is worn or in bad shape, this would be the time to replace it. If the new cassette has a different number of teeth in the larger cogs, you may need to lengthen or shorten the chain.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! Thanks for answering one of our questions, hopefully you'll answer more. To help you with that, we recommend that new members take the [tour], also check out [answer]. Good to see you here